# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que PHP detecte que sobrepasó el número?

Tags: php

Soy un newbie en PHP y no sé que estoy haciendo mal.
La idea es que el código termine cuando llegue a 200 pero al tener el `rand()` hay veces que llega hasta 203.
Ahora mi pregunta es ¿Cómo se puede limitar o hacer que PHP sepa que al llegar al 200 se detenga?

```
$cazul=0;
$cblanco=0;
$cnegro=0;
$crojo=0;
$meta=false;

while ($meta==false) {


$cazul=$cazul+rand(1,5);
$cnegro=$cnegro+rand(1,5);
$cblanco=$cblanco+rand(1,5);
$crojo=$crojo+rand(1,5);

echo "caballo azul: ".$cazul." metros"."\n" ;
echo "caballo negro: ".$cnegro." metros"."\n" ;
echo "caballo blanco: ".$cblanco." metros"."\n" ;
echo "caballo rojo: ".$crojo." metros"."\n" ;
echo "-----carrera puestos----"."\n";

sleep(1);

 if ($cazul <=> 200 xor $cblanco <=> 200 xor $cnegro <=> 200 xor $crojo <=> 200) 
 {
    $meta=true;
    exit("La carrera finalizó \n");
 }


}
```

[image: Un screenshot de mi terminal.]

Ahí añadí un screenshot de la terminal mostrando como llega hasta 300 el valor.

Comment: if ($cazul <= 200 xor $cblanco <= 200 xor $cnegro <= 200 xor $crojo <= 200) 
 {
    $meta=true;
    exit("La carrera finalizó \n");
 }  me parece que debes quitar el mayor que

Comment: llegó hasta 202 el valor.

Comment: lo que sucede es que compara mientras sea menor o igual que 200 genere el random y lo sume al valor es decir si tiene 199 y random 4 el resultado será 203 pero el colega @Pedro Gonzalez te dio una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no quieres que el valor supere los 200m, deberás limitar lo valores de las variables. Una posibilidad sería hacerlo así

```
$cazul=min(200, $cazul+rand(1,5));
$cnegro=min(200, $cnegro+rand(1,5));
$cblanco=min(200, $cblanco+rand(1,5));
$crojo=min(200, $crojo+rand(1,5));
```

La función **min** devolverá el valor más pequeño de los dos que se le pasan, de esta manera nos aseguramos de que el resultado nunca sea mayor de 200. Luego cambia la comprobación de esta manera

```
if ($cazul == 200 or $cblanco == 200 or $cnegro == 200 or $crojo == 200)
```

Como sabemos que ahora nunca va a ser mayor que 200, usamos una comparación de igualdad y el operador que uso es or, no xor

Comment: Muchas gracias Pedro! La comprobación me devuelve siempre que ganó el caballo azul, pero ahora entiendo como tendría que ser.

Comment: @IanH Diria que el caballo azul gana porque corre el doble de rápido porque lo tienes definido dos veces seguidas, y va agregando valores el doble de veces que los demas. Así cualquiera gana las apuestas :-)

Comment: Uh, no me di cuenta de que lo tenía dos veces. Muchas gracias por la corrección. Saludos!

Comment: No, solamente que el colega @Pedro Gonzalez duplico la variable $cazul en el [link](https://onlinegdb.com/gS4HOdmO8) esta modificado

Comment: @pperez PedroGonzalez no lo duplicó, venia mal de la pregunta y tampoco se dio cuenta. En tu enlace ha ganado el blanco la primera ronda... jolin... he perdido un dineral apostando por el azul! :-D

Comment: Gracias @masterguru buen detalle porque al correr el primer script siempre ganaba el caballo azul, con razón si había trampa digamos que se dopaba con código para ganar.

Comment: Cierto, en el código original estaba duplicada la sentencia para calcular el caballo azul y no me di cuenta. Ya está corregida la respuesta